# Disabled button color is not rendered correctly in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In Chrome, a disabled button is displayed with blue color and border color, background color as expected. But in IE9 text color is shown as grey.

**css**:

```
 fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
    .btn-default.disabled:focus,
    .btn-default[disabled]:focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
    .btn-default.disabled.focus,
    .btn-default[disabled].focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.focus,
    .btn-default.disabled:active,
    .btn-default[disabled]:active,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,
    .btn-default.disabled.active,
    .btn-default[disabled].active,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-color: #ccc;
    }
.st-btn-default {
  border: 2px solid #227ab9;
  padding: .49rem .75rem;
  color: #227ab9;
}
```

**html**:

```
<input id="buttonPrev" type="button" class="localize btn btn-default st-btn-default" lang="previous" value="Previous" disabled>
```

Comment: I do not understand your question, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix some grammar mistakes and to remove the bold from text. If all question is emphasized then none is. Good luck!

Comment: In chrome browser the disabled button text is showing in blue color, but in IE9 browser the same button text is displayed in grey color.

Answer (score 0):

disabled attribute is partially working in IE9
[check here for more details](http://caniuse.com/#search=disabled)